# Running a Levene's test over a list instead of separate vectors

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, variance

I am analysing a number of data sets for homogenous variance using [scipy.stats.levene()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levene.html). I have each one of my data set in a separate column that I put into pandas dataframes and drop NaN values.

My problem is this - I have a lot of samples - and would like to run the test simultaneously on all data sets in a list (eg. something like list_of_samples = list(df.columns.values). But all my attempts at this give me the error message *ValueError: Must enter at least two input vectors*.

All help and feedback is greatly appreciated!

My code so far.

```
### Import modules

import scipy
import csv
import pandas as pd

### Open dataframe, drop one column and NaN values

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.drop(['Object'],axis=1)
df = df.dropna()

### Put sample data in dataframe by column

sample1 = df['column1']
sample2 = df['column2']
sample3 = df['column3']
sample4 = df['column4']

w = scipy.stats.levene(sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4)[0]
pvalue = scipy.stats.levene(sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4)[1]

    if pvalue<0.05:
            Result = "Data shows variance"
            scipy.stats.levene
        else:
            Result = "Data shows no variance"

print(w, pvalue)
```

Comment: You are putting the same column in all samples. That is not the reason for your problem, but still good to know.

Comment: `levene(*[smple1, sample2, sample3])` should work

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I cleaned the example code to make it easier to follow. My real code insert each sample correctly. This is not the problem. Thx for pointing it out! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution by using the [pingouin module](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.homoscedasticity.html), which is based on [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levene.html#scipy.stats.levene). pingouin allows the test to be run on data in list format (organized either Long and Wide)

I found it very helpful to review the meaning of [Long and Wide data](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/wide-and-long-data/), and also [dependent and grouping variable](https://www.statisticshowto.com/grouping-variable/).

Below is an example code

```
import numpy as np
import pingouin as pg

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
test = pg.homoscedasticity(data, dv='column1', group='column2', method='levene', alpha=0.05)
```

The output is a float with the following format.

```
               W      pval  equal_var
levene  1.583536  0.066545       True
```